# Upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.1 but site doesn't display

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I've upgraded my VPS from 14.04 to 16.04.1 on an Apache 2 web server and the upgrade seemed to be successful. But now my site no longer displays. Instead it shows a "This site can't be reached ... refused to connect" error.

**Edit:** I executed `sudo services apache2 status` and the result is somewhat convoluted for my limited knowledge.

[image: image 1]

However, the error log returns the following error:

[image: image 2]

Although the error log points to the SSL certificates, there is nothing wrong with them that I can see. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Do you seriously expect to get any help without providing even the most basic info like what technologies your site is running on?

Comment: The site is running on an Apache 2 web server.

Comment: Then your first order of business should be to check whether Apache is even running. You can do this with the following command `sudo service apache2 status`. If it's not running you should start it with `sudo service apache2 start` and check for any errors. If it's already running you can restart it with `sudo service apache2 restart` and if that doesn't help - check the contents of `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (or whatever the right path is if you have modified it) for any useful information.

Comment: Please see the edits in my original post.

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814))? Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone at all please help?